# sifr3 multiple font faces in one .swf? for fonts that don't have bold or italic weights?

Tags: sifr

I have a font which only has a regular weight… I’d like to use another font as the bold weight and another as the italic weight… and have sifr use the extra fonts as a replacement based on strong and or b tags

I’ve tried embedding the multiple fonts in the .swf but only the regular weight get’s applied when sifr is activated. If I have two separate .swf font files I can the text to generate in either font but can't seem to apply the bold version to the bold text in the sentence.

Is their a smarter way to do this? using sifr3 - r436 with CS3 Flash Professional to create the font files

Answer (score 2):

Okay after an hour os do googling various terms I found this

http://discuss.joyent.com/viewtopic.php?id=24567

which answers my question - I now have the whole family embedded as I need

Thanks

R